# SQL Server 2008 , asp.net MVC 3 C# Getting Data from one table to another when the value is null . . the data in the other table kicks in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
var applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles
                             join app in context.APPLICANTs
                                 on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id
                             where app.Profile_id == a.PROFILE_ID
                             select app).Take(1000);
```

this is the statement but i need to change it. . .

i need to find how to fetch the values from the Profiles table when the value of the LastName and Firstname fields is null on the Applicant Table

In Applicant table . . there is a foreign key Profile_id.

Thanks for who can help me .

Answer (score 3):

```
var applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles
    join app in context.APPLICANTs
    on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id
    where app.LastName == NULL & app.Firstname == NULL
    select a).Take(1000);
```

Comment: it didn't recognize the "and" statement

Comment: use "&" operator instead of "and"

Comment: should i select the context of profiles or the applicant context?

Comment: It depends on you. 
If you need only data of profiles table than you select profile.
If you need only data of applicant table than you select applicant.

Comment: i need the data from profiles when the Lastname and Firstname in applicant is null . . 

what should i select

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29967/discussion-between-enrique-gil-and-bappi-datta)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.net mvc3 with c# then operator should be like &&. i.e.

```
var applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles
    join app in context.APPLICANTs
    on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id
    where app.LastName == NULL && app.Firstname == NULL
    select a).Take(1000);
```

Comment: should i use the profile context. . . i need the applicant context

Comment: As per my knowledge, profile and Applicants are two different things..means if you want data from Profiles,use Profiles  For e.g. `var app=from p in db.Employees                                                                           join e db.Designation on p.DesignationID equals e.DesignationID`. Due to this you get employee record with designation name which is stored in Designation table. I hope this solves your problem